# Execute the next sql statement

Tags: plsql

In my db, tables:

- test1--not exist
- test2--exist
- test3--exist

While running the below block, it's throwing a "table does not exist" error for test1. However, I want to run the below drop statement for test2 and test3 despite the error because, for my case "does not exist" is fine for me as i am going to create all the 3 tables in the next step.

```
set serveroutput ON;
BEGIN
    begin
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table test1';
    dbms_output.put_line('test1 dropeed successfully');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table test2';
    dbms_output.put_line('test2 dropped successfully');
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table test3';
    dbms_output.put_line('test3 dropped successfully');
    exception
        when others then
            dbms_output.put_line('Error >> '|| SQLERRM ||' -->'|| dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
    end;
end;
```

expecting:- it should drop test2 and test3 as well , even if we got the table doesnot exist error for test1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture the exception for each drop statement:

```
SET serveroutput ON SIZE 999999
CLEAR screen
DECLARE
  table_or_view_dne EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (table_or_view_dne, -942);
BEGIN
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE test1';
   EXCEPTION WHEN table_or_view_dne THEN
     NULL;
   END;
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE test2';
   EXCEPTION WHEN table_or_view_dne THEN
     NULL;
   END;
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE test3';
   EXCEPTION WHEN table_or_view_dne THEN
     NULL;
   END;
  END;
/
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to capture the "table does not exist" error explicitly and ignore it, which you can do like so:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE drop_table(table_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name;
    dbms_output.put_line(table_name || ' dropped successfully');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF SQLCODE != -942
    THEN
      RAISE;
    END IF;
  END drop_table;
BEGIN
  drop_table('test1');
  drop_table('test2');
  drop_table('test3');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error >> ' || SQLERRM || ' -->' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
END;
/
```

Note that I created a sub-procedure that drops the table; that avoids replicating the same logic over and over.

---

If you want to declare the exception (as per Ken's answer), which is probably better and easier to understand, you could modify the above code like so:

```
DECLARE
  table_not_exists EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (table_not_exists, -942);

  PROCEDURE drop_table(table_name IN VARCHAR2) IS
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE ' || table_name;
    dbms_output.put_line(table_name || ' dropped successfully');
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN table_not_exists THEN
      dbms_output.put_line(table_name || ' didn''t exist');
  END drop_table;
BEGIN
  drop_table('test1');
  drop_table('test2');
  drop_table('test3');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Error >> ' || SQLERRM || ' -->' || dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
END;
/
```